# Rendering MXML component only after actionscript is finished

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, mxml

In my mxml file, I'm doing some calculations in the script tag, and binding them to a custom component.

```
 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

   [Bindable] public var calc1:Number;
   [Bindable] public var calc2:Number;

            private function init():void {
               calc1 = //calculation;
               calc2 = //calculation;
            }
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>

    <mycomp:Ball compfield1="{calc1}" compfield2="{calc2}"/>
```

The problem is that the mxml component is being created before the actionscript is run. So when the component is created, it actually doesn't get `calc1` and `calc2` and it fails from that point. I know that binding happens after that, but the component and its functions have already started and have run with the null or 0 initial values.

My solution was to create the component also in actionscript right after `calc1` and `calc2` have been created. This way I get to control precisely when it's created

```
 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

   [Bindable] public var calc1:Number;
   [Bindable] public var calc2:Number;

            private function init():void {
               calc1 = //calculation;
               calc2 = //calculation;

               var Ball:Ball = new Ball(calc1, calc2);
            }
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>
```

but this is creating all kinds of other problems due to the way I've set up the component.

Is there a way I can still use mxml to create the component, yet control that it the `<myComp:Ball>` gets created only after `init()` is run and `calc1` `calc2` evaluated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your vars to zero values first:

```
   [Bindable] public var calc1:Number = 0;
   [Bindable] public var calc2:Number = 0;
```

Then call the function on creationComplete:

```
<mycomp:Ball 
   compfield1="{calc1}"
   compfield2="{calc2}"
   creationComplete="init()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out and get back.

Comment: Didn't really solve my problem, but I'm guessing it has something to do with my code, so I'm choosing this as it seems like a valid answer. Thanks for the help.